# Jetpack Compose: Text content changing when switching phone's orientation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make a `Composable` with a clickable `Box` that update a text when you click on it.

The following code does it, but it is also updating when changing the phone orientation, which is not desirable.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun WordDisplay() {
    var text: String by remember {
        mutableStateOf(nextWord())
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .clickable(onClick = { text = nextWord() })) {
        AutoResizableText(
            text = text,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge.copy(fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge.fontSize * 10)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that the `text` variable used in the `WordDisplay` composable is being recomposed every time the configuration changes, including when the phone orientation changes. This is because `remember` is used to store the value of `text`, and it will be recomposed whenever the composable's inputs or the configuration change.

To prevent the recomposition of `text` when the phone orientation changes, you need to use a different approach to preserve the state across configuration changes. One way to do this is by using the `rememberSaveable` instead of `remember`. The `rememberSaveable` function is specifically designed for retaining state across configuration changes.

Here's the modified code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun WordDisplay() {
    var text: String by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(nextWord())
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().clickable(onClick = { text = nextWord() })) {
        AutoResizableText(
            text = text,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge.copy(fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge.fontSize * 10)
        )
    }
}
```

By using `rememberSaveable` instead of `remember`, the `text` variable will retain its state across configuration changes, and the text won't be updated when the phone orientation changes.

Comment: sounds nice except the code in the OP *already* uses `rememberSaveable`.